# University counselling agent chatbot to integrate in a website

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I need to create a university counselling agent for my dissertation which means that I need to create a chatbot which fetches information from the university website. If I want to build my chatbot user interface in html/css, what chatbot platform and chatbot language should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

I am using api.ai in my project which for build a chatbot for sales agency

I think you can try it